# Commit and Rollback is not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I got the answer for one of my problem from the question posted by me [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012886/how-to-rollback-or-commit-a-transaction-in-sql-server)

I got this solution

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    exec( @sqlHeader)
    exec(@sqlTotals)
    exec(@sqlLine)
COMMIT
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 1
    ROLLBACK
 END CATCH
```

After getting the solution I'm facing a new problem which is, it's working fine first time when the stored procedure executes, after that its giving following error

> *Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.*

I need your help.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? And please remove the tags for the versions you aren't using.

Comment: Ok. I'm using 2008-r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error is occurring and the rollback isn't happening because there is a mistake in the code. The rollback and the check for it should be:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK
 END CATCH
```

After the commit, @@TRANCOUNT will be zero. If an error occurs, the @@TRANCOUNT will be 1. In the original code, that didn't trigger the rollback but it should have.