# Is it possible to rollback a SQL Server transaction without suppressing the error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013018/125292) provides an elegant way to use TRY CATCH ROLLBACK TRANSACTION, but it suppresses the error information.

Is there any way to rollback a transaction that doesn't suppress the error that resulted in the rollback in the first place?

Here's an example T-SQL script based on the above method:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY )

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1), (1)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Useful to tag with the version of SQL Server you're using, then people don't have to guess if a potential solution will work for you or not.

Comment: PS `THROW` does not work in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Catch statement get the error code and message.  Then simply RAISE it again.  The following shows a few examples.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

(per RBarryYoung in the comments)

In the `CATCH` clause, just use [THROW](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx)

Comment: They don't show it at the link, but in the later versions of SQL Server, you can just use a generic `THROW` in the `CATCH`, instead of having to respecify it with a `RAISERROR ...`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I was hoping for a less manual method than RAISEERROR. Throw seems like what I was looking for. Thanks! Please post that as an answer and I'll select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Let's let ChrisLively amend his answer instead, he's only one word off, and it's a pretty short answer either way.

Comment: Bummer! Throw was introduced in SQL Server 2012. I'm stuck with SQL Server 2008R. THROW is still the right answer in my mind, but I'm going to have to resort to RAISEERROR for the time being. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: I had a trouble when using `IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END` and then doing `THROW`. It works if you remove the `BEGIN ... END` around the `IF` statement

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I'm including the equivalent of THROW for SQL Server 2008R here.

This is from the section labeled "Returning error information from a CATCH block" at the following page:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=sql.105).aspx

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- RAISERROR with severity 11-19 will cause execution to 
    -- jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
    -- information about the original error that caused
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
               );
END CATCH;
```

Comment: But is this really equivalent to `THROW`? Your method does not retain the error number or the line number; it creates a new error and raises it. Your method also does not terminate the batch, but `THROW` will. -1 because the answer is misleading.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Then what is your SQL 2008R2 equivalent to `THROW`?

Comment: @robertc I suppose I don't have one, but this certainly isn't equivalent. That's all I was getting at. I'd recommend a SQL Server upgrade if you're still on 2008 R2 in 2017; it will save you some headache later to do small upgrades instead of one large upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray We can recommend our clients upgrade their SQL Servers but we can't force them to do it, unfortunately

Comment: @robertc You can certainly decline to work on legacy systems or push them toward an upgrade path. I started charging a 15% fee on top of base cost every 2 years after official support (security patches) has ended for a given Microsoft product. People upgrade pretty quick, even with larger systems. You get more business, make the world safer, and in the end the client is better off... or they'll hate you in short order. I've had few issues though after some explanation.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Yes, I could choose to quit my job, but I'm not going to do it over that

Comment: @robertc Not quite what I meant, haha. But fair enough, it depends on the situation.