# Why is this not returning an @@ERROR?

Tags: sql, transactions

I'm trying to do basic import routine within a Transaction so I can ROLLBACK/COMMIT as required, as well as alert the person via a screen message.

When the file is missing / not found I get the following error:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Cannot bulk load. The file "FileToImport" does not exist.

However this error message above does not seem to cause @@ERROR to increment...

I ROLLBACK/COMMIT based on @@ERROR <> 0 as you can see below

What am I missing?

Here is an outline of my code:

```
-- Start Transaction
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @MyFile varchar(255)
SET @MyFile = 'FileToImport'

DECLARE @sql_string nvarchar(max)
SET @sql_string = N'INSERT INTO Some Table ....
.... FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @MyFile +''',FORMATFILE=''MyImportFormatFile.XML'',FIRSTROW = 2) as BulkLoadFile'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_string;

-- Check For Error. If Error then print out a message to the screen and ROLLBACK
IF @@ERROR<>0
BEGIN
print('')
print('ALERT!!! There was an error and this step did NOT Commit to Database')
Print('')
ROLLBACK
SET NOEXEC ON
END

-- Since @@ERROR = 0 we can Commit Transaction (assuming something happened) and print out a message to the screen
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 COMMIT TRANSACTION
SET NOEXEC OFF
PRINT ('')
PRINT ('FINISHED & COMMITTED')
PRINT ('')
-- End Transaction
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: do you have an ON ERROR RESUME NEXT hidden somewhere off-screen?   If you are using SQL Server 2005+, you might want to switch to TRY..CATCH error handling.

Comment: **NOT** using ON ERROR RESUME NEXT. I will look into TRY..CATCH Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things. First of all, the @@Error actually increments. See the following:

[image]

Also, the transaction actually Rolls Back, however, when I debug your query, I see the debugger jumping to SET NOEXEC OFF immediately even before executing the IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 statement or other statements. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx : When SET NOEXEC is OFF, all batches are executed after compilation. I believe this is why you are seeing the just the print statement that does indicate it is complete, but actually it is not.

I found a great example of Transactions and how they actually should be written. Please check [How to rollback or commit a transaction in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012886/how-to-rollback-or-commit-a-transaction-in-sql-server)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks!    That link to **How to rollback or commit a transaction in SQL Server** is great and incorporates the TRY..CATCH suggested by @Tab Allerman. Before I go and completely rewrite the wrapper, I'm going to short-cut it and make that an IF/ELSE vs two IF statements... It really should have been done that way to begin with.

Comment: I was just thinking about what you said **"I see the debugger jumping to SET NOEXEC OFF immediately even before executing the IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 statement or other statements"**   All of this is part of  a big Daily Update Routine which is run from shell like...    
echo.    
SQLCMD Step1.sql    
echo.    
SQLCMD Step2.sql    
echo.    
SQLCMD Step3.sql    
Each StepX is isolated in its own Transaction wrapper, but am I getting spillover from previous steps with SET NOEXEC ON|OFF?    
i.e. Should I start each step by explicitly setting SET NOEXEC OFF?

Comment: My question would be what is the use of SET NOEXEC ON|OFF? SET NOEXEC ON|OFF compiles the query but just does not execute them. The transaction will roll anything back as long as it is setup to catch the errors so, even though it may execute the query, it will roll it back up. If there is another use of SET NOEXEC, let us know and we can find a work around.

Comment: Thank you again SOD... I just noticed something when doing a debug. I actually have a print command right after the Execute command **EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_string;
print('... Importing DSF.csv');** which is causing my @@ERROR to go back to 0 from 4860 right before my IF @@ERROR <>0.  I left this line out of my example as I figured it was innocuous but apparently it is not... Now I need to get a better understanding of how @@ERROR works, as I thought it was a cumulative error count but it seems it is not...  WOW... One Question = LOTS of learning.