# Rollback to a previous save point in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

Read some documentation but it seems I just cannot get it.

I have some transactions like this:

```
begin transaction
   statement 1
   statement 2
   statement 3
commit
```

What I would want to do is something like this:

```
begin transaction
   if statement 1 fails then rollback from beginning else create savepoint1
   if statement 2 fails then rollback from beginning else create savepoint2
   if statement 3 fails then rollback from beginning else create savepoint3
   if everything is successfully executed then commit
```

Any hints for the syntax? The statements are just some inserts and updates for the same table and the current setup gave me a deadlock.

Regards,

Comment: In theory this is exactly how it is going to work - why do you get into deadlock... that is difficult to say without more details (tables, data, actual inserts)

Comment: What is "rollback from beginning"? If you mean "rollback everything", that's just `ROLLBACK`. Or, indeed, not doing anything special at all except issuing a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the top, so the first failed statement aborts the transaction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rollback or commit a transaction in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012886/how-to-rollback-or-commit-a-transaction-in-sql-server)

Comment: I don't want to get into the details why I've got the deadlock in the first place, long story short that due to the begin transaction in the top of the block of the sql code, it seems that the lock was on the page file (if I've understood it correctly) and had to use save points in order to be able to process rest of the updates and inserts on that specific table. I've updated my initial question. Thanks

Comment: If your transaction encounters a deadlock, it is *dead*. Deadlock is an error that causes batch abortion (not statement abortion) with rollback. No savepoint will help you. You can use a `TRY .. CATCH` to catch the error itself, but your transaction is doomed and no more data modification statements can be executed in it. Source: [Erland Sommarskog's article on the matter](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification).

Comment: it's a little bit complicated...that's why i just wanted an example for savepoints and rollbacks...

Comment: [That's covered in the article as well](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#SAVETRAN). Or if you like, there's examples in the [documentation for `SAVE TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql).